# Atributos y métodos estáticos en Java. Consideraciones que debemos tener en cuenta

Tags: java, static

En ocasiones nos puede interesar tener en una clase Java un atributo que no tenga valores independientes para cada instancia de la clase, sino que su valor sea compartido por todas las instancias que existan o se creen de dicha dicha clase (atributos o métodos estáticos).

Dado que el contexto estático (cuando se carga la clase en memoria) se crea antes que el contexto dinámico (cuando se crean las instancias), no es necesario que creemos una instancia de la clase para acceder a un método o atributo de tipo estático.

Por contra, desde un contexto estático no podemos acceder a ningún atributo o método que no esté definido como estático (ya que puede que todavía no se hayan creado instancias del objeto), pero desde un contexto dinámico sí que podemos acceder al contexto estático.

Esto es útil cuando queremos mantener un contador del número de elementos de un objeto, ya que si no definimos el atributo como estático, cada vez que se cree una nueva instancia del objeto el atributo será inicializado con los valores por defecto (cero para numéricos y null para objetos) o los que le hayamos indicado en el constructo.

Ejemplo:

Clase Dispositivo de Entrada:

```
package com.gm.mundopc;

public abstract class DispositivoEntrada {
    private String tipoEntrada;
    private String marca;
    
    /* Constructores de la clase */
    public DispositivoEntrada(String tipoEntrada, String marca){
        this.tipoEntrada = tipoEntrada;
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    
    /* Getter y Setters de cada propiedad */
    public String getTipoEntrada(){
        return this.tipoEntrada;
    }
    
    public void setTipoEntrada(String tipoEntrada){
        this.tipoEntrada = tipoEntrada;        
    }
    
    public String getMarca(){
        return this.marca;
    }
    
    public void setMarca(String marca){
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    
    /* Para poder imprimir el objeto */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DispositivoEntrada{" + "tipoEntrada=" + tipoEntrada + ", marca=" + marca + '}';
    }
}
```

Clase Teclado:

```
package com.gm.mundopc;

public class Teclado extends DispositivoEntrada{
    private final int idTeclado;
    private static int contadorTeclados;
    
    /* Constructores de la clase */
    public Teclado(String tipoEntrada, String marca){
        super(tipoEntrada, marca);
        this.idTeclado = ++contadorTeclados;
    }
    
    /* Para imprimir el objeto */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teclado{" + "idTeclado=" + idTeclado + '}';
    }
}
```

La duda que se me presenta es. ¿Qué consideraciones debemos tener en cuenta a la hora de definir un método o atributo de forma segura?

Por ejemplo, creo que al trabajar con Threads hay que tener cuidado y crear mecanismos para que si varios hilos acceden a la clase en un mismo momento no modifiquen el valor.

¿Podríais ayudarme con esta duda que tengo?

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Si la preocupación está en el acceso concurrente de varios hilos, es una cosa. Si la preocupación es la seguridad, ya es otra cosa (p.ej. usar módulos desde Java9). Yo revisaría si la pregunta va de _definir de forma segura_ o qué es lo que realmente te preocupa.

Comment: La pregunta se refiere a las consideraciones que debería tener en cuenta a la hora de definir un método o atributo como estático. Tanto a nivel de seguridad, como de concurrencia o cualquier cosa que sea relevante para un buen diseño (partiendo de la base de lo que ya conozco y he comentado en la pregunta). Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es interesante, pero corre el riesgo de ser demasiado amplia, además de no mostrar ningún esfuerzo por entender / resolver el problema (no digo que seas un vago, sino que en la pregunta no aparece nada de lo que has investigado ni qué dudas o problemas tienes en base a lo investigado). Me parece que [este post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety) aborda de manera amplia el problema que se te plantea aquí. Como podrás ver, hay varios tipos de enfoques para resolver el problema del *Thread-Safety*.

Comment: Al final del post referido más arriba hay un enlace a un repositorio de Github, donde profundiza mucho más sobre el problema, con enlaces a una veintena de artículos: [parte 1 del repo](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/core-java-modules/core-java-concurrency-basic), y [parte 2 del repo](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/core-java-modules/core-java-concurrency-basic-2).

Comment: Lo primero de todo, gracias por la parte de la respuesta que ayuda a resolver la duda que planteaba en esta publicación. Sobre lo de que no he investigado, decirte que eso es un juicio de valor y no me voy a molestar (ni tengo por qué) en justificarme.